# Android preferences how to work with switch statement

Tags: android, switch-statement, android-preferences, onpreferenceclicklistener

I have some preferences in my preference screen:

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:key="category"
    android:summary="Category"
    android:title="Category">

    <Preference
        android:key="pref1"
        android:summary="desc"
        android:title="Pref 1" />

    <Preference
        android:key="pref2"
        android:summary="desc"
        android:title="Pref 2" />

</PreferenceCategory>
```

Finding them in `PreferenceActivity`:

```
Preference pref1, pref2;

@Override
    protected void onCreate(final Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      pref1 = findPreference("pref1");
      pref2 = findPreference("pref2");
}
```

And set some `OnPreferenceClickListener` to them. How do I correctly define which preference was clicked? I'd like to do it in case-switch style, but I cannot figure out which types should I use:

```
Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener listener = new Preference.OnPreferenceClickListener() {
    @Override
    public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
        switch (???){       //I guess, here goes the "preference"?
            case ???:       //getting error with pref1 or pref2

        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

If I put `preference` from `onPreferenceClick` in `switch()`, I will get errors with `case`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get the corresponding preference like

```
@Override
public boolean onPreferenceClick (Preference preference)
{
    String key = preference.getKey();
    // do what ever you want with this key
}
```

ref: [Preference Activity on Preference Click Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15536908/preference-activity-on-preference-click-listener)

hope this helps :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the field `key` of Preference

```
public boolean onPreferenceClick(Preference preference) {
    if (preference.getKey().equals("pref1")) {
        ... do something ...
    } else if (preference.getKey().equals("pref2")) {
        ... do something ...
    }
    return true;
}
```