# Design Decision: Should I use Broadcast Receiver or static classes

Tags: android, oop, architecture, broadcastreceiver

I am working on the PreferencesActivity of an App:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity

Pref. activity looks something like this :
https://i.stack.imgur.com/Piquy.png

There are some actions we need to take when the user selects or deselects options in this Pref. Activity (which involve turning services on/off, making a connection to DB etc.)

Currently, most of the logic to take this action is written in the activity itself (the activity is huge) and some static classes.

We now want to save these settings on the server and perform these actions on user login (without launching the pref. activity). How should I move the logic?

To completely static classes? To individual broadcast receivers? Something else?

Image taken from here:
[Preference Activity on Preference Click Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15536908/preference-activity-on-preference-click-listener)

Answer (score 0):

Create `PreferencesStorage` class, which load asynchronously settings from server, and send changes in preferences to the server.
Then use this class in your `PreferenceActivity` and `SplashActivity` (if you use di - then inject this class as singleton, if no - use instance of this class).
If some of settings need to be readed in every activity - yes, I think `BroadcastReceiver` will be best solution.

If you want to use clean architecture approach, then you can create `PreferencesInteractor`, which includes `PreferencesRepository`, and inject this interactor to `SplashPresenter` and `PreferencesPresenter`.