# Android: How to set an OnPreferenceClickListener on a Preference?

Tags: java, android, sharedpreferences, onclicklistener

I am new at Android programming and firstly I would like to make a simple options menu demo with SharedPreferences. I have created the basic structure, but I have no idea how to attach OnPreferenceClickListener to the Preference. Nonetheless, I can use onSharedPreferenceChanged method, but there are no other event listeners. (Again, I am a beginner so I don't know why this is so.)

I have read a documentation about the steps of creating a menu: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/settings/customize-your-settings#java

I have also seen a question here: [Preference Activity on Preference Click Listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15536908/preference-activity-on-preference-click-listener)

I have tried some of the solutions, but they didn't work at all. (I couldn't implement OnPreferenceClickListener, so that could be the main reason, but I don't know why)

As you can see I created a CheckBoxPreference and a Preference elem in a PreferenceCategory. (This is in /res/xml/settings_pref.xml)

```
<PreferenceCategory
    android:key="category_basic"
    android:title="Basic settings">
    <CheckBoxPreference
        android:defaultValue="true"
        android:key="my_checkbox"
        android:summaryOff="Off"
        android:summaryOn="On"
        android:title="@string/my_checkbox"
    />
    <Preference
        android:key="my_preference"
        android:title="@string/my_preference"
    />
</PreferenceCategory>
```

This method checks the state of the CheckBoxPreference (checked / not checked)
(This is in /java/MainActivity.java)

```
@Override
public void onSharedPreferenceChanged(SharedPreferences sharedPreferences, String key) { // called when I change the state of the CheckBoxPreference
    if (key.equals("my_checkbox")) {
        // some interesting stuff
    }
}
```

But my aim is to detect if the user clicked at a Preference and do something (for example open a dialog box)

```
onClickPreference.setOnPreferenceClickListener(preference -> {
    // do something
    return true;
});
```

When I tried out to create a click listener, I got this error message: Cannot resolve symbol 'onClickPreference'

Comment: share full code of MainActivity that have Preferences, and more code can help

Answer (score 2):

Try this code hope it will help you

```
findPreference("my_preference").setOnPreferenceClickListener(preference -> {
    // do something
    return true;
});
```

Comment: The only problem is that it is deprecated as mentioned in the documentation: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/preference/PreferenceActivity.html#findPreference(java.lang.CharSequence). So probably that's the reason why I'm getting this error message: Cannot resolve method 'findReference(java.lang.String)'

Comment: In my case, I am running this code in Android 8 without error,  maybe the problem is with your IDEA, invalidate cache and restart, rebuild or clean project, hope it will help